# Linq C# query for combining multiple ARRAY_CONTAINS into a list

Tags: linq

A field with name 'Field' is checked against multiple values, right now am doing something as shown below:

```
ARRAY_CONTAINS(Field, "Value1")) OR 
ARRAY_CONTAINS(Field, "Value2")) OR 
ARRAY_CONTAINS(Field, "Value3"))
```

Instead is there a Linq query equivalent to just do something like Field.Contains("Value1", "Value2", "Value3"). If one exists, how is it written as Linq expression. Thanks!

Comment: If you make value1, value2 and value3 into a list or array then you should be able to use linqs intersect method on your other array to get the intersection between the two arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Enumerable.Intersect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect?view=netcore-3.1) for the purpose.

```
if(sourceArray.Intersect(elementsToSearch).Any())
{
}
```

Where elementsToSearch to search are collection of values you want to compare against.